# Is it possible to make an element enter into the viewport from bottom, using only tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm implementing a cookie consent popup. I want it to appear from the bottom of the page.

Is it possible only using tailwind?

I can't use `animation-bounce` since it's a bad user experience, because user needs to be able to click on the **OK** button.

I also know that you can use a lot of animations and transitions, on `hover:` or other pseudo classes.

But in my case, I want it to only appear from the bottom, without user interaction.

Can I do that?

Comment: You can do something like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/4WnC0VG0Kp

Comment: @brc-dd can you send you comment as an answer so that we can refer to it later? And can you explain a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you will need to use keyframes to create the custom animation. This is what I coded for a line which moves from left to right:

```
// Inside theme.extend in tailwind.config.js
        keyframes: {
            'moving-line': {
                from: {
                    width: '0px',
                    opacity: '0',
                },
                to: {
                    width: '30%',
                    opacity: '0.6',
                },
            },
        },
        animation: {
            'moving-line': 'moving-line .8s ease .5s forwards',
        },
    },
},
```

Then you can use it as `animate-moving-line` in the element's className. To make it appear from bottom, use translate-y property and create your own animation like above.